# Do questions about using VMWare belong on Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, scope

If you'd asked me 15 minutes ago I'd have said that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324881/why-after-installing-vmwaretools-the-vm-wont-enter-in-unity-mode) question should be migrated to Super User, no doubt.

However there's already a [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156809/why-do-people-vote-to-close-perfectly-good-questions-how-can-it-be-improved) discussing it in regards to whether it's a real question or not. In this question no one has suggested that it belongs on Super User instead, in fact the only mention of Super User is from the OP in a comment to an answer, and he's not really advocating it as such.

This puzzles me, if I had the power to vote I'd definitely put it up for migration, but apparently no one else has despite it receiving quite a lot of attention. All I can assume is that there's something I don't understand about migration, or where VMWare questions belong.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139177/stack-overflow-questions-about-virtualization-tools

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions on installing software/configuring are more suited for Super User.

> where VMWare questions belong.

VMWare questions do belong on Super User (and we have [few of them](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vmware%7E))

In this specific case:

- There's no mention of the guest OS
- There's no mention of the host OS
- No mention of what DE is being used
- No mention of what *version*/edition of VMware is being used (no, mentioning "latest" version doesn't cut it.)

As a [Super User moderator](https://superuser.com/users/4377/sathya), I'm very happy it was closed on Stack Overflow as "not a real question", because if it did come over to Super User, I'd close with the same reason & [leave](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/114?m=2696563#2696563) a [piece](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/114?m=6840384#6840384) of [my mind](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/114?m=6257454#6257454) in the [Ask a Super User Moderator Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator)

Comment: ah, I see. Is it SE standard practice that quality comes before relevance? By that I mean, it could be argued that a question should be put in front of the correct community first, and then let them judge it's quality (as they're the most qualified to do so). (i.e is Close before Migrate, rather than Migrate before Close, the SOP for SE?)

Comment: @Ian The golden rule for migrations is [don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22don%27t+migrate+crap%22+user%3A1). Having a bad question on the correct community doesn't do any good, turd is turd everywhere. Certain cases, can be taken as an exception but no - it's quality first

Comment: fair enough, I shall make a note for when I get to 3k. Thanks.

Comment: I have to say that from the SF perspective, we'd agree with @sathya - we're happy to accept questions about sysadmin questions related to VMware's ESXi infrastructure, etc. as these are on topic for us, but this particular question is rather low quality and we'd prefer not to see it. People who talk about installing the latest version of "VMWare" are no different to people who talking about installing "Microsoft". Not helpful.

Comment: Closing a question  often penalizes someone for not being as knowledgeable as some moderator would like him to be, especially when the grounds are "vagueness." Moderators often conflate generality (high level of abstraction) with vagueness. A general question is not vague. (Are tigers mammals, is general but not vague.) The reason someone not knowledgeable cannot make the question more concrete is often that he does not have the concrete information or even know which concrete information is relevant. Guidance on such head would be much better than just closing.